# Suggestions for common authentication and authorization system for Linux and related applications

Tags: linux, authentication

I plan to implement a common authentication and authorization system for several linux applications. Some examples to use that AA system is:
xl2tpd, pptpd, openvpn, squid and some custom made web applications. Do you know any ready system for undertaking such a mission? I mean a system, with user and role management including. That system may have some authenticator system binary that results in grant or reject, and other tools may be configured for using thgat binary for checking authentication and authorization.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Would something like [FreeIPA](http://freeipa.org/page/Main_Page) work for you? It bundles stuff like LDAP and Kerberos in one package and makes administering that "easy" - you are talking about very complicated stuff, anyway.

Comment: Actually, I will not manage a network of computers. I have a one firewall device. It has several services. I want create and manage users, give them roles for manager, vpnuser, internetuser roles. When the user connect to for example to vpn service, if he has arole of vpnuser and credentials are true, i will be allowed to make vpn connection.

Comment: I am happy to know FreeIPA, as well. However I think it is not designed for my purpose but designed to be a complement to AD and to be AD of non-Windows machines. Also I can not find any info on roles management of FreeIPA.